# d3 transition circles to a json data value

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to set up a force directed layout in d3 and have my nodes start with an initial radius at 0. I then want for the user to be able to press a button and have the radius of the nodes scale to a size in accordance with a json data value. When I try to do this however, I get a javascript error "Cannot read property 'FIELD4' of undefined.

Here is the json data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/2n7do

And here is the code:

```js
// Update nodes.
  
    circles = circles.data(data);

    circles.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = circles.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.FIELD5); })
      .style("opacity", 0.75)
      .call(force.drag);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 9)
        d3.select(circles).transition()
        .delay(3000)
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.FIELD4 * 0.000195 });;
```

Comment: You don't need the `d3.select(circles)`, just `nodeEnter.append("circle").attr("r", 9).transition().delay(3000).duration(1000).attr("r", function(d) { return d.FIELD4 * 0.000195 });`.

Comment: I tried this and the visualization appeared but then instead of transitioning to the new size, all of the nodes disappeared altogether. And now I'm getting this javascript error: "Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute r="NaN""

Comment: You also need to convert the string to a number, so `.attr("r", function(d) { return +d.FIELD4 * 0.000195 });`.

Answer (score 0):

circles is d3 selection. By doing `d3.select(circles)` you select selection. I don't think it's valid.
Instead of `d3.select(circles).transition()` try `circles.transition()`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change anything. The nodes are all still appearing with a size 9 radius instead of transitioning to the data value.

Here is the code:

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 9)
        circles.transition()
        .delay(3000)
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r", function(d) { return data.FIELD4 * 0.000195 });;

Comment: try: var actual_circle = nodeEnter.append("circle"); Then actual_circle.transition().attr("r", function(d) { return (+d.FIELD4) * 0.000195 });